# Splash Screen with HTML5 in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, splash-screen

I am trying to create a Splash Screen with html5 code embebed in iOs. I have been looking for some example but I didn't find anything. Does anyone know something about it?

Thank you.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, just create a UIViewController with an UIWebView inside and present the Controller in the application didFinishedLaunching Method, as long as you want 1 unto n Seconds

Comment: According to Apple's guidelines, there is no such thing as a "splash screen"

Comment: Btw. always check www.whathaveyoutried.com when asking questions... ...this will actually increase the quality and number of answers to your questions! And please work on your accept-rate...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made one intermediate UIView that the app loads first in the window. Then the app loads the rest of the data and change the root view of the window.

It works! :)